# 1 Peter 2:3, what is the literal translation of the Greek and Latin text?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 2:3 (GNT):

> 3. εἴπερ ἐγεύσασθε ὅτι χρηστὸς ὁ Κύριος.

1 Peter 2:3 (Latin Vulgate):

> 3. si gustastis quoniam **dulcis** Dominus

1 Peter 2:3 (DRB):

> If so be you have tasted that the Lord is **sweet.**

What is the literal translation of both, Greek and Latin text?

I think DRB is faithful to the Latin Vulgate, but other Greek dependant translations are not the same with the Greek text.

1 Peter 2:3 (KJV):

> 3. If so be ye have tasted that the Lord {cf15I is} gracious.

Does χρηστὸς in the verse mean kind, gracious or good?

Look Adam Clarke Commentary [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.studylight.org/commentary/1-peter/2-3.html&ved=2ahUKEwiZxIm2_fDpAhWL5OAKHcF1ApUQFjAGegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0p7TO-jYNfipsqZScnoqtU) .

Look also [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.behindthename.com/name/christos&ved=2ahUKEwjYv4-3iPHpAhVIzYUKHTxeAz0QFjADegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0F8NkxogN21nf1nK9EVCsQ&cshid=1591579929172) .

Comment: [χρηστὸς](http://biblehub.com/greek/5543.htm) (*chrestos*), similar to [χριστός](http://biblehub.com/str/greek/5547.htm) (*christos*), means *good* (morally, or otherwise); applied to taste, it might reasonably be translated as *sweet*. (As an aside, many Greek-speaking pagans interpreted Jesus' title as the former, rather than the latter, inasmuch as *anointed* did not have the deep implications for Europeans -and others- as it did for Orientals, whose kings were indeed physically anointed, and who commonly employed myrrh instead of water for washing one's hair or body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1 Peter 2:3 the Greek text is:

> εἰ ἐγεύσασθε ὅτι χρηστὸς ὁ Κύριος [NA28],  OR, εἴπερ ἐγεύσασθε ὅτι
>   χρηστὸς ὁ κύριος [Byzantine text]

(Both versions give the same results.)  Some good representative literal translations of this include:

- NASB: if you have tasted the kindness of the Lord.
- BLB: if indeed you have tasted that the Lord *is* good.
- YLT: if so be ye did taste that the Lord is gracious,

Note that these all translated the Greek χρηστὸς with either "kindness", "good", or, "gracious".  These are all reasonable translations of χρηστός (chréstos) according to BDAG.

The Latin translation "dulcis" which means "sweet" (DRB) is presumably on the basis of taste, but the literal meaning of the Greek is "being morally good and benevolent".  I assume that the Latin has stretched such a characteristic people to being sweet which is idiomatically correct but not literally correct.

Comment: what about χρηστὸς means Christ?

Comment: No - Christ is Χριστός (Christos) - similar but different word.